# Why can't I get an email address to be accepted by Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

In Microsoft Outlook emails from a trusted source continue to be placed in **Junk**.

- The email address is in my contacts
- I've selected "always trust emails from..."
- I've even created a rule that says "all emails from this address are to be placed in the inbox"

#### So why do they continue to be placed in Junk?